# Javascript: How to check only one item in checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Please help, I failed to code the checkbox that can only checked 1 item. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Html

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="<%=Name %>" onClick="return checkbox(this)" >
```

Javascript

```
function checkbox(a) {

var Count = 0;

if (a.checked)
{
Count = Count + 1;

}

if (Count == 2)
{
alert('choose One Please');
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: That's what a radiobox is for

Comment: No applicable, for my case.

Comment: It will always return 1 as you are initializing your NewCount variable to 0 at the beginning of the KeepCount function.

Comment: Dear @KBorja, so how should i declare the NewCount variable ?

Comment: Declare to 1 or compare NewCount==1. Any thing is fine and NewCount should be declared globally as it will reset after every function call to 0

Comment: @user3835327 you can declare and initialize it outside the function, not sure if it's the best approach though.

Comment: @KBorja see the another approach I specified in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring count inside a method hence it will always be initialised to 0 when you click on check box. Hence declare count globally and maintain the count.

```
 var NewCount = 0;// global declaration


function KeepCount(a){

     if (a.checked){
          NewCount = NewCount + 1;
     }else{
          NewCount = NewCount - 1;
     }

     if(NewCount>1){
       alert('Pick Just One Please');
       return false;
     }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Another approach if you don't want to add variable globally:

**HTML**

```
Group 1
<input type="checkbox"  value="1" name="test[1][]" onclick="addClassCheck(this)"/>
<input type="checkbox"  value="1" name="test[1][]" onclick="addClassCheck(this)"/>
<input type="checkbox"  value="1" name="test[1][]" onclick="addClassCheck(this)"/>
<br/>
Group 2
<input type="checkbox"  value="1" name="test[2][]" onclick="addClassCheck(this)"/>
<input type="checkbox"  value="1" name="test[2][]" onclick="addClassCheck(this)"/>
<input type="checkbox"  value="1" name="test[2][]" onclick="addClassCheck(this)"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function addClassCheck(element){

    if(element.checked){
        element.classList.add("marked");
    }else{
        element.classList.remove("marked");
    }

    if(document.getElementsByClassName("marked").length>1){
      alert("Please select only one check box");
        element.checked=false;
        element.classList.remove("marked");
    }

}
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9b2sn4uc/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Group your checkboxs as

```
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="test[1][]" />
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="test[1][]" />
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="test[1][]" />
<br/>
Group 2
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="test[2][]" />
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="test[2][]" />
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="test[2][]" />
```

Query

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']";
        $(group).prop("checked", false);
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/zGEaa/1946/)

Comment: I guess he is using pure JavaScript

Comment: Sorry bro, im not using jquery coding and my checkbox name is currently replace with java code <%=sFieldName %> for some purpose.